# How to share a variable from usercontrol1 to usercontrol2

Tags: vb.net

I'm using form1 which contains Usercontrol1 and form2 which contains usercontrol2.

In usercontrol1 a webbrowser is extracting a link and I'd like to pass this link to usercontrol2 becuase It will create a QR code with google api.

So, in usercontrol1 I am not using nothing else than just webbrowser extracting the link.

I tried to declare a public "link" but it doesn't work.

In usercontrol2 I have:

```
     Dim sitoGoogleQrCode As String = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs={WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}&cht=qr&chl={TESTO}"
            sitoGoogleQrCode = sitoGoogleQrCode.Replace("{WIDTH}", PictureBox1.Width.ToString()).Replace("{HEIGHT}", PictureBox1.Height.ToString()).Replace("{TESTO}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(usercontrol1.link))
            Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()

            Dim bytes As Byte() = client.DownloadData(sitoGoogleQrCode)
            client.Dispose()
            Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytes)
            Dim bmpQrCode As Bitmap = New Bitmap(memStream)
            PictureBox1.Image = bmpQrCode
```

There is a way to use that Usercontrol1 link variable in this code in usercontrol2?

```
WebUtility.UrlEncode(usercontrol1.link))
        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
```

Thanks

edit1: Using 3rd Laancelot code:
In Usercontrol code:

```
    Public Class Usercontrol1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
dim link as string= webbrowser.getelement etc..

        Dim UC2 As usercontrol2
        UC2.DoSomething(link.tostring)
    End Sub
End Class
```

While in Usercontrol2 code:

```
    Public Class Usercontrol2
    Public Sub DoSomething(importantInformation As String) '<- I think is missing something on 3r code.
          Dim sitoGoogleQrCode As String = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs={WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}&cht=qr&chl={TESTO}"
            sitoGoogleQrCode = sitoGoogleQrCode.Replace("{WIDTH}", PictureBox1.Width.ToString()).Replace("{HEIGHT}", PictureBox1.Height.ToString()).Replace("{TESTO}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(UC2.link))
            Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()

            Dim bytes As Byte() = client.DownloadData(sitoGoogleQrCode)
            client.Dispose()
            Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytes)
            Dim bmpQrCode As Bitmap = New Bitmap(memStream)
            PictureBox1.Image = bmpQrCode
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I'm doing wrongly?

Comment: Where is the code that calls `Form2`? Where is the `link` variable? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When UserControl1 creates the form with UserControl2, it can gives itself as a parameter and thus you can relate it with UserControl2 as needed.

Comment: Kshkarin, I did ask right because I don't know how to call usercontrol2 from usercontrol1 , so as a consequence, I don't know also how to call form2 from form1. . 
I mean, If I knew, I wouldn't ask it . 
Link variable is just a simple string I'm extracting from webbrowser which Is a link, and this link needs to go in usercontrol2 to create the qr code.

Comment: @laancelot, what you mean with that?

Comment: You passed `importantInformation` succesfully but you're not actually using it yet.

Comment: Probably it is missing something on your last 3 rd code example.. I Did exactly what you did in there

Answer (score 0):

Here's some skeleton code to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
Public Class FormA
    Public Property SomeValueIWantToShare As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim formB As FormB(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FormB
    Private myFormA As FormA

    Public Sub New(formA As FormA)
        myFormA = formA
        ' then later you can get the property you need like this:
        Dim stringFromA As String = formA.SomeValueIWantToShare
        ' if the text you need is in a textbox, for instance, it could be this:
        Dim anotherString As String = formA.ThatTextBoxWithTheString.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Alternatively, if you already know the information you need when you instantiate Form2, you can just give it that information instead:

```
Public Class FormA
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim formB As FormB(ThatTextBoxWithTheString.Text)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FormB
    Public Sub New(importantInformation As String)
        DoSomething(importantInformation)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomething(importantInformation As String)
        ' do stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or:

```
Public Class FormA
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim formB As FormB
        formB.DoSomething(ThatTextBoxWithTheString.Text)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FormB
    Public Sub DoSomething(importantInformation As String)
        ' do stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

I can answer questions as needed. Have fun!

Comment: Hi laancelot, I needed communication between two usercontrols, not forums. 
Can I change forma with usercontrol1 and formb with usercontrol2?
Do i need to declare the form anyway?

Comment: @user14441867 You can pass anything as a parameter, I added some more options so you get the general idea. I'm not sure what your question means, though, if you care to explain further I'll try to help.