# Combobox value is not being passed to the next form(which is a module), stays empty

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Form1 has a user select a value from combobox, then they click next button to go to StatusModule. I want that item selected from Form1 to be used in an If/else statement in the module to create a client and return the results. Currently, with my break point, everything works besides the value is not being passed from Welcome to StatusModule.

Form1:

```
Public Class Welcome
Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click

If AdapterSelection.Text = "USB" Or AdapterSelection.Text = "USBC" Or AdapterSelection.Text = "HDMI" Then
            If ELocation.Text = String.Empty Then
                EValidFalg = False
                MessageBox.Show("Select an E file.")
                ELocation.Text = "Select E"
            Else
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            End If
        Else
            DValidFlag = False
            MessageBox.Show("Select D")
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub AdapterSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdapterSelection.SelectedIndexChanged
        If AdapterSelection.Items(0) <> "" Then
        Else
            AdapterSelection.Items.Add("USB")
            AdapterSelection.Items.Add("USBC")
            AdapterSelection.Items.Add("HDMI")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Module:

```
Module StatusM
Function Start()
 client = CreateObject("E File")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'Display some error information
            Screen.Display.Text = "ERROR: Fail to create client"
        Else
            Debug.Print("Completed")
            Debug.Print(Welcome.AdapterSelection.Text) 'NOT SHOWING ANY VALUE

            If Welcome.AdapterSelection.Text = "USB" Then
                "My Code"
            ElseIf Welcome.AdapterSelection.Text = "USBC" Then
                 "MyCode"
            ElseIf Welcome.AdapterSelection.Text = "USBC" Then
            End If
End Function
End Module
```

Comment: I've written [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354812/5844572) earlier today. If the problem is "how to share the information from one form to the other" it may help.

Comment: @laancelot Thank you for the reference, it helps, but my second "Form" is a module. I am trying to give inputs into first form, that passes those values into a module and then returns the results into another form(3). I got all of that down besides passing combobox value to module (form2)

Comment: Then change your function to receive the string in the first place: `Function Start(ByVal selection As String)`, then call it with: `Start(AdapterSelection.Text)`?

Comment: Modules are great but they are like Shared methods, you'll have to carry around your data from overload to overload. When something like this happens to me and there's a lot of data to carry around, I create a class just for storing the data and limiting the overload to one thing.

Comment: "...and then returns the results into another form(3)."  You can't return the results to Form3 (if that is really a form), if the `Start()` function is being called from Form1.  You can technically iterate over the Forms collection and find Form3, but this is a really bad design.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Let me try to create that function. I am new to this, I might not be using correct terminology? Not capture the results, but Display them in Form3, that part works too..just the passing of my combobox value doesnt.